# Hide top header until scroll to certain height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and I want to implement something like this: (klook app)

[image: Klook scroll]

It's basically a button being shown when the user scrolls a bit.

I tried different things with a SliverAppBar and [SliverStickyHeader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header), but I can't make it work like this. I also played with Opacity and Visibility but it moves my hole view and does not 'overlap' my banner/searchby widget.

My code so far:

```
class _ExplorePageState extends State<ExplorePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool lastStatus = true;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (isShrink != lastStatus) {
      print("listen");
      setState(() {
        lastStatus = isShrink;
      });
    }
  }

  bool get isShrink {
    return _scrollController.hasClients &&
        _scrollController.offset > (400 - kToolbarHeight);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverStickyHeader(
            header: Visibility(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: isShrink ? 100 : 0,
                child: Text('Header 1'),
              ),
              visible: isShrink ? true : false,
              maintainState: true,
              maintainSize: true,
              maintainAnimation: true,
            ),
            sliver: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  BannerWidget(),
                  ButtonWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The BannerWidget and ButtomWidget are two Containers similar to the app shown above.

I hope you can help me or tell me maybe what this behaviour is called.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried placing a `Stack` with your view and the widget that you want to display on top of it and then playing with any `Opacity` widget to show/hide when the offset is at a certain point? It should be easy enough. Just let me know if you need an example.

Comment: You mean Stack [Sliver, topWidget] ? I'll try it

Comment: Damn why didn't I came up with this yesterday... Thank you very much.
I just wrapped my CustomScrollView inside a Stack and wrapped my button inside an Opacity after my CustomScollView.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you @shiiboun.

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with using `CustomScrollView`, you could use `SliverPersistentHeader` with your own delegate. It will allow you to access current header scroll state and make your own layout depending on how much space you have left.

[image: demo]

```dart
const double _kSearchHeight = 50.0;
const double _kHeaderHeight = 250.0;

class _ExplorePageState extends State<ExplorePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: DelegateWithSearchBar(),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      child: Text('test'),
                      color: Colors.black26
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DelegateWithSearchBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final showSearchBar = shrinkOffset > _kHeaderHeight - _kSearchHeight;

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: !showSearchBar ? 1 : 0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('xxx'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  )
                ),
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 20),
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Sample Text',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: showSearchBar ? 1 : 0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          child: Container(
            height: _kSearchHeight,
            color: Colors.white,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('search bar')
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate _) => true;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => _kHeaderHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _kSearchHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Igor, this looks also very good and thank you for your example! But for now I'll try Miguels solution.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to solve my issue. Perfect!!!